# Spring Native Unresolved class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I got this error after running the docker container generated with `gradle clean bootBuildImage`

> 2021-11-13 14:49:11.425  WARN 1 --- [           main]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'dgcImpl' defined in class path resource
> [com/user/test/beans/dgc/impl/dgcImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'cpImpl' defined in class path resource
> [com/user/test/beans/dgc/impl/cpImpl.class]: Bean instantiation via
> constructor failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.user.test.beans.dgc.impl.cpImpl]: Constructor threw
> exception; nested exception is
> kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError: Unresolved
> class: class com.user.test.beans.dgc.impl.TrustList

Edit:

```
class TrustList{
    var certificates: List<PublicCert> = listOf()
}
```

in cpImpl I parse a TrustList from a json, this will be also called in the constructor (in kotlin init):

```
val parsedTrustList = Klaxon().parse<TrustList>(json)
```

Comment: Hi, care to share some code? Looks like `TrustList` and `cpImpl` are a good place to start. please edit your question and add some more content.

Comment: thanks for the reply I edit the issue, is this enough or do you need more code?

Comment: I think Klaxon does reflection stuff and thats the problem do you know how to fix that?